# ASP.NET MVC 5 consumir data api por post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, api, asp

alguien que pueda ayudar con el siguiente problema...?

Estoy consumiendo datos a una API usando HttpClient pero me devuelve lo siguiente

> {"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."}

Tengo lo siguiente:

El response de la API me devuelve esto:

```
{
"rows": {
    "recordsets": [
        [
            {
                "Monto": "1000000",
                "CantidadDias": 50,
                "TasaDiaria": "0.009700000000000",
                "TasaPeriodo": "0.48",
                "MontoInteres": 4800,
                "MontoFinal": 1004800
            }
        ]
    ],
    "recordset": [
        {
            "Monto": "1000000",
            "CantidadDias": 50,
            "TasaDiaria": "0.009700000000000",
            "TasaPeriodo": "0.48",
            "MontoInteres": 4800,
            "MontoFinal": 1004800
        }
    ],
    "output": {},
    "rowsAffected": [
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    "returnValue": 0
}
```

}

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:0000/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("authorization");

            var DAP = new Simulador() { Monto = 1000000, CantidadDias = 50 };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DAP);

            Simulador Simulador = new Simulador();

            try
            {
                // GET Method
                HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync("api/simuladorDAP", new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                if (HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var EmpResponse = HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    Simulador = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Simulador>(EmpResponse);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw(e);
            }

            return View(Simulador);
        }
```

Model:

```
public class Simulador
{
    public int Monto { get; set; }
    public int CantidadDias { get; set; }
    public int TasaDiaria { get; set; }
    public int TasaPeriodo { get; set; }
    public int MontoInteres { get; set; }
    public int MontoFinal { get; set; }
}
```

Quien seria tan amable de indicarme como lo deveria hacer o que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias.

Comment: Has identificado que linea exactamente te da el error?

Comment: En el IF se cae, donde la respuesta me devuelve false en vez de devolverme un status OK, tal vez sea problema del modelo por la forma en que esta el json, nose D:

Comment: Revise bien, y se cae aca -> HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync("api/simuladorDAP", new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

Comment: El error que me devuelve e -> No se puede obtener acceso al objeto desechado.
Nombre del objeto: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.

Comment: El error que te esta dando dice que no esta inicializado el objeto antes de esa linea incializalo `HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();`

Comment: El objeto lo tengo inicializado antes del try{}...  Simulador Simulador = new Simulador();